# For microservices which are continually communicating over gRPC to each other, might it make sense to keep the connections open (persistent)?

Tags: microservices, grpc

I am exploring possibly using gRPC for inter-service communication.

I know gRPC is good for streaming communication. However, I'm not sure if it is intended for connections that never close (until one side dies).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can close on both side explicitly. I'm not sure what language are you using, but there should be an API to do this.

Comment: So, my question was whether it might be more efficient to keep the connections open? and if so, does gRPC allow for it/have others done this?

Comment: gRPC has corresponding TCP connection underlying its Channel object, and the TCP connection MAY be shared across Channel objects if their destinations are the same. So, as long as you don't explicitly call `Channel.close()`, the connection will live on (there is an idle feature that will close the TCP connection after no traffic for a long period of time like an hour).

Comment: Back to your question, it would be more efficient if you keep the TCP connection on. On the other hand, if the "connection" in your question means the streaming RPC, the influence becomes much smaller. The overhead is extra HEADER_FRAME, and HTTP2 Stream creation. It would be a trade-off the application owner should decide between resources and performance.

Comment: If you are curious about the actual performance difference between unary-unary call and streaming call. You can refer to our performance dashboard: https://performance-dot-grpc-testing.appspot.com/explore?dashboard=5652536396611584.

Comment: Thanks. When you say it would be a trade off "between resources and performances"...when I think of resources, I think of the socket open on the machine as well as whatever memory to hold information about the stream. Anything else you're thinking of?

Comment: I think your examples resources make sense. I will add one more, TCP ports are also precious resources. Long-live connections will consume TCP ports pretty quickly, and limit the number of ongoing RPCs.